# Impossible to execute a command by using su for another (system) user

Tags: su

I've created my user like this:
    `sudo adduser --disabled-password --system --home /var/lib/deluge --gecos "Deluge server" --group deluge`

The content of `/etc/passwd`:
`deluge:x:110:114:Deluge server,,,:/var/lib/deluge:/bin/false`

The directory I'm in :

```
root@xxxxxx:/var/lib/deluge/.flexget# ls -al  
drwxr-xr-x 2 deluge deluge 4096 15 mars  11:39 .  
drwxr-xr-x 7 deluge deluge 4096 15 mars  11:40 ..  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 deluge deluge 3881 15 mars  11:39 config.yml
```

What I'm trying to do :

```
su deluge -c "flexget --test execute"
```

But nothing happens, I've got no error shown, I also tried just `su deluge` but the same still root.
How can I run a command using this user ? (I'm not using `sudo`)

Comment: Try supplying the complete path to `flexget`.

Comment: Even `su deluge -c "touch /var/lib/deluge/.flexget/test"` does not work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `deluge` user has `/bin/false` for their default shell - this is what `su` is running and passing the `-c` option to (or running without any options when you simply do `su deluge`). You can use the `--shell` option to `adduser` to set a shell when creating the user. Eg:

```
sudo adduser --shell /bin/sh --disabled-password --system \
  --home /var/lib/deluge --gecos "Deluge server" --group deluge
```

Or use `chsh` to change the shell for an already created user:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/sh deluge
```

Or you could use the `--shell` (or `-s`) option with `su` to override `/etc/passwd`:

```
su deluge -s /bin/sh -c "flexget --test execute"
```

Depending on what else your are doing with the user, `/bin/bash` might be a more appropriate shell to use.